# CodeIgniter +HMVC error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc-codeigniter

1st-time setup CodeIgniter HMVC. when I run the code I face this error. An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error

> Message: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_object_to_array()
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ciall\hmvc\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 300
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ciall\hmvc\application\modules\foo\controllers\foo.php
>   Line: 23 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciall\hmvc\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: Now ok......Thank You !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the MY_Loader there is a problem with the HMVC and latest version of codeigniter and best to use this

Link here https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss

The person in charge of HMVC has not fixed it yet

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader
{
    /** Load a module view **/
    public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        list($path, $_view) = Modules::find($view, $this->_module, 'views/');

        if ($path != FALSE)
        {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path => TRUE) + $this->_ci_view_paths;
            $view = $_view;
        }

        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => ((method_exists($this,'_ci_object_to_array')) ? $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars) : $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars)), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```

Hope this helped if does please accept answer